# polyglossia Warning: totalhyphenmin:'n'

Tags: polyglossia

I use polyglossia with LuaLaTeX.

Sometimes I get a warning like that, in strange places (beginning of the document, or `\tableofcontents`...):

```
Package polyglossia Warning: totalhyphenmin:'5' on input line 21.
```

Can someone figure out, why, or how to do in order to avoid such warnings?

A perhaps interesting detail: I’m preparing a small package to typeset books in Spanish or Italian. If I compile the same text with main language = italian, I don’t get any warning; with spanish, I do.

EDIT: as suggested by egreg, here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage{latin}% otherwise polyglossia complains about lipsum text

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

By compiling with LuaLaTeX, I get the warning: `Package polyglossia Warning: totalhyphenmin:'5' on input line 8.`

With `\setmainlanguage{italian}` instead of Spanish, the warning disappears. The warning disappears also if I let `\setmainlanguage{spanish}` but compile with XeLaTeX. (Helas, I must use LuaLaTeX for other reasons...)

NEW EDIT: perhaps this can have something to do with my issue: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/111

Comment: Please, make a small selfcontained example that shows the issue.

Comment: @egreg: thank you, MWE added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see this code in `polyglossia.sty`

```
   \ifluatex
     % Set \totalhyphenmin if specified
     \prop_get:NxNTF \polyglossia@langsetup {#2/totalhyphenmin} \l_tmpa_tl
     {
        \xpg@warning{totalhyphenmin: '\l_tmpa_tl'}
        \expandafter\hyphenationmin \l_tmpa_tl%
     }%
     {}%
```

so when `totalhyphenmin` is set by a language you get the warning. Indeed,
we find

```
\PolyglossiaSetup{spanish}{
  bcp47=es-ES,
  hyphennames={spanish},
  hyphenmins={2,2},
  totalhyphenmin=5,
  langtag=ESP,
  frenchspacing=true,
  indentfirst=true,
  fontsetup=true,
  babelname=spanish
}
```

in `gloss-spanish.ldf`.

Quite likely, whoever added the code mistook `\xpg@warning` for `\xpg@info`: one doesn't want the user to be warned about something the package developers deliberately used.

I added a comment to the [relevant GitHub issue report](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/111#issuecomment-1026640840)